# Oracle database not compatible with oracle business intelligence 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, business-intelligence, obiee

I'm following the below tutorial to install Oracle business intelligence 12c on Linux 7.7
,my Oracle database is already installed and working fine.

http://bisoftdiary.com/obiee12c_linux_installation/

when I run the script ./config.sh
after reach to this step it says ensure the database is compatible,I really don't understand what is wrong with my database ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check pre requisite check section for details about failed reason. And share

Comment: @Tejash I have updated the question as you can see my perquisites check section are all good .

Comment: You never said which database version you have installed on that computer.

Comment: @Littlefoot it was a password issue,and the error message doesn't explain clearly the issue with password ,it just saying ensure the database is compatible ,I think Oracle should correct this message .

Answer (score 1):

I have passed the issue by making the password more complex, but unfortunately the error message doesn't tell me the issue with my password ,it should mention clearly the issue with my password so I can correct it.

Comment: If you look into the detailed log files it does actually tell you the error... Just have to read the log files.

Comment: @Chris I wanted to check the log but as you can see the first screenshot it doesn't tell you which log file to check,in other steps when an error comes up it will mention which log file to be checked .

Comment: Not sure I subscribe to that logic. No need for a GUI to tell me where which log file lies. Part of being an IT professional is to go look for things, read, think, and find out.

Comment: Hint: The OBIEE documentation tells you where to look for the logfiles: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/biee/BIESG/GUID-464861F6-CD14-443F-9251-E1C5300CEB02.htm#BIESG1674.  (But I can't check that the installer *does* record the information you were looking for in the log.)