# PreReq Check for create new schema failed

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, obiee

create new schemas All attempts failed. The first problem was with connecting string After solving the problem, we have a second problem PreReq Check for create new schema failed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtkRn.png)

Comment: It says "Ensure that the Database being used is compatible".  Have you done that?  What exact version of Oracle database *are* you using?

Comment: You may find more information in the logs; see https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/biee/BIESG/GUID-464861F6-CD14-443F-9251-E1C5300CEB02.htm#BIESG1674

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59478993.  From the screenshot, it looks like you have weak passwords, and that may be what OBIEE is complaining about ... per the related question.